How to show sign-in screen before main screen?
I’m making an iOS app in Xcode using Swift. I have my launch screen and this goes to the main storyboard after it’s loaded. I have made a signup/login page and would like this to appear after the launch screen. Had a look about and can’t find anything as of yet. Any help would be much appreciated.
Order would be: Launch screen - sign in - main
I have look at different methods but not seen one that looks to be what I’m after

Make sign in as root view controller instead of Main screen

You can do it Like this Making Deeplink and also rootViewController to specific ViewController
static func decideAndMakeRoot(displayVc: UIViewController,nextVc:UIViewController? = nil) {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        let nvc = UINavigationController(rootViewController: displayVc)
        Helper.getInstance.makeSpecificViewRoot(vc: nvc)
        if let nextVc {
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now()+1) {
                nvc.pushViewController(nextVc, animated: true)
            }
        }
    }
}

///set specific view controller as root
public func makeSpecificViewRoot(vc: UIViewController){
    var snapshot: UIView?
    var rootVC: UIViewController?
    rootVC = vc
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        snapshot = (UIApplication.shared.windows.first(where: \.isKeyWindow)?.snapshotView(afterScreenUpdates: true))
        if let snapshot, let rootVC {
            rootVC.view.addSubview(snapshot);
            UIApplication.shared.windows.first(where: \.isKeyWindow)?.rootViewController = rootVC;
            UIView.transition(with: snapshot, duration: 0.4, options: .transitionCrossDissolve, animations: {
                snapshot.layer.opacity = 0;
            }, completion: { (status) in
                snapshot.removeFromSuperview()
            })
        } else {
            print(" No snapshot found")
        }
    }
}

